# Do I have to declare explicitly that point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have already defined 2 nodes `crect` and `celli`, and I would like to draw a line from `crect` to the point on the right of `celli`, it seems that the following does not work:

```
\draw[->] (crect) -- [right=1cm of celli];
```

So do I have to declare explicitly that point by `\node`? Does anyone have a solution to make it work in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `calc` library and its syntax for coordinate calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (1,1) {A};
  \node (B) at (3,1) {B};
  \draw (A) -- ($(B) + (1cm,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also `[x|y]shift` your desired coordinates. No need of `calc` library in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (1,1) {A};
  \node (B) at (3,1) {B};
  \draw[red] (A) -- ([xshift=1cm]B.center);
  \draw[green] (A) -- ([yshift=1cm]B.center);
  \draw[blue] (A) -- ([shift={(1cm,1cm)}]B.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You need to use `B.center` (or any other node's coordinate) and not just its name. Note also the brackets envolving parenthesis in shift.