# addition in \coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I have to declare explicitly that point?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27322/do-i-have-to-declare-explicitly-that-point)

How do you define a new `\coordinate` as the sum of two other coordinates?

I often end up with a setting such as this

```
\coordinate (leg) at (4, 1.5);

\coordinate (base) at (leg)+(0,0);
\draw (base) +(-.1,-.1) rectangle +(.1,.1);
\draw (base) + (.1, 0) node[right]{analyticity region}; 

\coordinate (base) at (leg)+(0,-.5);
\draw (base) circle(.2);
\draw (base) + (.1, 0) node[right]{neighbourhood};
```

But the two blocks are drawn on top of each other. Apparently you can not do something like `\coordinate (A) at (B)+(C)`, can you recommend a workaround? I would prefer no ugly constructions with `pgfmath`, or at least to hide them.

Thanks

Comment: you can use calc library of TikZ. Then you would write `($(A)+(B)$)`

Comment: You can use `\path (B) ++(C) coordinate (A)`.

Comment: With `calc` library of TikZ, you can use `\path let \p1=(A),\p2=(B) in (\x1+\x2,\y1+\y2) coordinate (C);`